# Bootstrap : how to distribute fixed size grid cells in different screen sizes, and when resized

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

I do have a requirement to distribute a variable number of fixed size divs in a bootstrap based page. Means it is uncertain how many columns for a row, however each grid cell in different screen sizes should be equal in size.

[For example see attached image. I have 15 fixed size divs. See how I need them distributed in different screen sizes. I did try with different bootstrap grid classes, but none helped so far. It will be a great help if any of you can guide me how I can achieve this using bootsrap.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfQGo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Working Demo: Run the code in Snippet and view with full page mode with resizing the browser size to verify correct div are visible.

Hope it will help>

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-12 col-md-2 hidden-sm">1</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-12 col-md-2 col-sm-6">2</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-12 col-md-2 col-sm-6">3</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-12 col-md-2 hidden-sm">4</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-12 col-md-2 col-sm-6">5</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-12 col-md-2 col-sm-6">6</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-12 col-md-2 hidden-sm">7</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-12 col-md-2 col-sm-6">8</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-12 col-md-2 col-sm-6">9</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-12 col-md-2 hidden-sm">10</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-12 col-md-2 col-sm-6">11</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-12 col-md-2 col-sm-6">12</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-12 col-md-2 hidden-sm">13</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-12 col-md-2 col-sm-6">14</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-12 col-md-2 col-sm-6">15</div>
</div>
 </div>
```